# NGINX reverse proxy for multiple locations not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to run two express.js APIs in an EC2 instance with the help of PM2 and reverse-proxy using NGINX. Please find the NGINX config below,

[NGINX config for the locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRWbK.png)

My intention is to run the 2 APIs under the following routes:

1. `/` to reverse proxy `localhost:3000`
2. `/local` to reverse proxy `localhost:3001`

To make things more clear, I need the URL containing `/local` or `/local/` to proxy the API running on the port `3001`. However, when I try to hit `https://example.com/local` or `https://example.com/local/`, the response is received from the API running in port 3000 instead of the intended proxy.

This is the response returned when tried in the browser:

[Safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE1DS.png)

The solution needed is to successfully configure the 2 APIs to consume requests from the `/` aka root domain and the `/local` domain respectively. But both the requests go to the first one.

PS. I was also advised with a trick - tried switching the location positions (i.e. keeping the `/local` location block first followed by the `/` block) in the config file, still no luck - same behaviour.

Comment: don't screenshot text, just include the text here.  Your safari screenshot is pointless, it says nothing.  Please include `curl` example instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse proxy works fine redirecting the requests to the correct server, but the one running on '/local' gets requests forwarded containing '/local'. So the express app present there looks for /local in the route, but i figured out that was not configured. So have something like this.

```
app.get('/local', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World2!')
})
```

Just make sure to add the prefix '/local' for all the routes in the express app server at '/local' from nginx

And

"PS. I was also advised with a trick - tried switching the location positions (i.e. keeping the /local location block first followed by the / block) in the config file, still no luck - same behaviour."

The above will be the correct config because nginx will match and redirect the requests to the first applicable block. So if '/' stays before '/local' all the requests will be redirected to the first express app.

Comment: Hey Venkatesh, thanks for the answer. Yup, I resolved it via the same method and was confused since NGINX proxied the request along with the /local prefix to the express app. I made changes in the app to support this change and works fine now.

However, is there any option to remove the /local while NGINX reverse proxies the request to the application internally?

Comment: I dont think you can do that.... the best u can do is to have multiple express routers configured under different route paths like
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/account', checkUser, routes.account);