# How to serve two back-end applications running on different ports with Nginx location?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-location

Boot and angular front-end applications are running on docker containers. I do own a domain and with Nginx reverse proxy to pass the requests for appropriate front-end, back-end which is spring-boot. Default 80 is serving my front-end for more clarification.

Pre details:

```
Sample domain  : xyz.com
Front-end app  : running on default port 80  
Back-end spring-boot app: running on port 8085
```

First part of my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name xyz.com;


    location / {
            root /var/www/site;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;


    location /api{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
    }

}
```

When I type `xyz.com` my website is up and running and some front-end routes:

```
: xyz.com/blogs
: xyz.com/images
: xyz.com/news
```

These are my rest routes in springboot back-end:

```
: xyz.com/api/article/getAll
: xyz.com/api/public/mail/sendmail
```

The interesting part is I can't serve my backend application which is running on port 8085.

This means whenever my URL comes with `/api/*` it should go to port 8085 but in my case it says "404 not found".

Why are my rest routes not working, did I miss something in my Nginx configuration?

Note: Spring boot container is working fine no issues in docker or application, I think the problem is from Nginx configuration particularly location block.

Comment: are both FE and BE on the same docker container?

Comment: FE & nginx are not in a container, Only the Spring-boot runs on Docker container port 8085 @xTheDoctah

Comment: So let me se if i got it clear,  those components Docker, Fe, Be and Nginx, are all on the same machine, but Springboot it's inside docker. Right?

Comment: @xTheDoctah Yes you seems right, All are in same server. FE, Nginx not inside the container. Only BE (spring-boot) is inside the docker

Comment: can you run docker port [container name] and see if if the "external_port" is right? (would be amazing if you can add the output to the post, censoring the ips(if public))

Comment: Yes it's accessible for outside the container, problem is not with docker or springboot. The real problem is with nginx location it recognize the url `mydomain/api` I can see the whitlabel error page but whenever I hit `mydomain/api/myroute` it false for 404

Comment: the i've the same exact configuration, the only thing i can point out its the space between /api and  the bracket .

Comment: Are you sure the 404 its not coming from your app?

Comment: 100% sure it's coming from Nginx. Because I can get a curl to my back-end `curl mydomain:port/get/All` for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

The block is serving the `/` first followed by the `/api`. This should be reversed and then things will work normally.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name xyz.com;

    location /api{
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8085;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header connection "upgrade";
    }

    location / {
            root /var/www/site;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

I had the same issue and got it resolved that way. Refer to [NGINX reverse proxy for multiple locations not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68513314/8299776) for more help.

Comment: You know what it seems when I type `xyz.com/api` this is showing white label error but routes are not working it says not found eg: `xyz.com/api/*/*` or `xyz.com/api/*`